# Android; triggering a volume_mounted: event, after manual mount

Tags: android, linux, unix

So, I mount something manually, for example to "/mnt/extsd". This works fine from shell, but the Android UI appears to want to be told of this, or it wont show in various applications, like that of the built in File Manager.

Normally, I guess what happens is that you insert new media, ueventd will tell vold, vold will mount the device, and sends "volume_mounted:" event on the /dev/socket/vold.

However, I am mounting it myself;

```
# zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/extsd mypool
# df
/mnt/private            15M     4K    15M   4096
/mnt/sdcard            939M     5M   934M   4096
/mnt/secure/asec       939M     5M   934M   4096
/mnt/extsd               1G    18M     1G   131072
```

In this case, File Manager will show "sdcard" as an option, but not /mnt/extsd.

sdcard is mounted thanks to /etc/vold.fstab:

> dev_mount       sdcard  /mnt/sdcard     auto  /devices/virtual/block/nandk

Long term, adding 'zfs' to vold might be the answer, but usually pools are automatically mounted, so it would be nice if I could simply send the event that volume was mounted.

Comment: Does firing the `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` help? Alternatively since you have the permission, write to the socket directly to simulate the event?

Comment: I have no way to send ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED from commandline presumably, but I could perhaps write something to do that. 
echo >> /dev/socket/vold does not work, but maybe if I got something more socket friendly it would work, like netcat..

Comment: `am broadcast -a "android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"` should work, there are multiple 're-scan' apps that do this to force external storage file list refresh.

Comment: I did not know about that command. On its own, it does not work. But I wonder what Android does when it gets the event, reads some mtab for mounted volumes somewhere, or queries vold?

Comment: Yes, it's just a trigger. Don't know the details off hand, but it scans files, checks for packages on external storage, etc. Check MountService.java for details.

Comment: Actually, that is half of the puzzle. It doesn't show up in the list of "attached devices" still, but sending the

    `am broadcast -a "android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" -d "file:///mnt/extsd"`


Makes the mediascanner go through it, and video/photos in the volume now show up in the photo/video/gallery applications. Fascinating.

Comment: This is sort of expected: the 'media' manager (which is now used for all files on external storage) tries to be independent from the actual volumes. Someone else (MountService?) is in charge of the attached devices list and it probably doesn't know how to handle zfs.